# Finde the difference in UPDATE in PostgreSQL

Tags: trigger, update, functions, audit

I would like to determine the *difference* in an UPDATE that was carried out on a table DE_projects. So between old and new values. **The aim is to monitor changes in the permissions column in the DE_projects table and insert this into DE_Log table.**

I have a function for that:

```
create or replace FUNCTION log_user_update() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin
    INSERT INTO DE_Log (tabname, operation, state, new_permission, old_permission)
        VALUES (TG_TABLE_NAME , TG_OP, new.state, new.permission , old.permission);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
```

and a trigger:

```
create Trigger log_user_permissions_update
    AFTER UPDATE of permissions ON DE_projects
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    WHEN (OLD.permissionsIS DISTINCT FROM NEW.permissions)
    EXECUTE FUNCTION log_user_update();
```

The function and the trigger work. The DE_Log table looks like this: For example, in the first line CC was deleted, so CC or if something was added like in line 2. Then DD.

| tabname | operation | state | new.permission | old.permission | *Difference* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE_projects | UPDATE | texas | AA BB CC | AA BB | CC |
| DE_projects | UPDATE | arizona | AA BB CC | AA BB CC DD | DD |

I tried this solution, but it returned me nothing: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4A6A75A5.4070203@intera.si